# Javascript destructuring of a supertest HTTP API response

Tags: javascript, jasmine, chai, supertest, destructuring

I am running Supertest, Jasmine and Chai to auto-test an HTTP API.

Expectations like this work:

```
    .expect( function(response) {
        expect(response.body.minVersion).to.equal(undefined)
        expect(response.body.errorMessage).to.equal("Incorrect parameters provided. This API requires a single \"path\" parameter. e.g. /file-compatibility?path=C%25%2FData%2FMy File.adicht")
        expect(response.body.result).to.equal("error")
    })
```

Whereas when I destructure the HTTP response I get an error [SyntaxError: Unexpected token { ]:

```
    .expect( function(response) {
        const { body } = response
        expect(body.minVersion).to.equal(undefined)
        expect(body.errorMessage).to.equal("Incorrect parameters provided. This API requires a single \"path\" parameter. e.g. /file-compatibility?path=C%25%2FData%2FMy File.adicht")
        expect(body.result).to.equal("error")
    })
```

It may be that this is not supported in one of these frameworks but I have being using ECMA 6 keywords such as 'let' and 'const' in the same file.

Comment: perhaps your environment (what is your environment? node? a browser? something else?) doesn't yet support destructuring fully

Comment: Yes this is being done in node.

Comment: well, node 7 understands the destructuring assignment

Comment: Okay, this is node 4. This could be where the problem lies.